# How to close a Persistent Bottom Sheet programatically in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to close a Persistent `BottomSheet` programatically in Flutter? Also is is there a way to show only a part of persistent bottom sheet and the user can drag the sheet upwards to view the full content?

The following code is to show the persistent bottom sheet.

```
homeScaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet<Null>((BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
      height: 300.0,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Text(
                'Persistent header for bottom bar!',
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              )),
          Text(
            'Then here there will likely be some other content '
                'which will be displayed within the bottom bar',
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
        ],
      ));
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can close the bottom sheet using

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `PersistentBottomSheetController` to close the bottom sheet. Here is how you'll do it.

```
PersistentBottomSheetController _controller; // instance variable
```

The following can be put in `onPressed()` type of event that would show bottom sheet.

```
_controller = homeScaffoldKey
    .currentState
    .showBottomSheet((BuildContext context) {
     return YourWidgetImplementation();
  },
);
```

And you can close it using

```
_controller.close();
```

> Also is is there a way to show only a part of persistent bottom sheet and the user can drag the sheet upwards to view the full content?

Sorry, you have to do it by your own, there is no inbuilt thing like this in Flutter as of now. You can use `GestureDetector` to manipulate the things your way.

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56189135/6618622)

Comment: is any way to know bottom sheet closed and opened?

Comment: You can set a `bool` flag to track it, you'll be the one to open the sheet, so put `flag = true` and when you close it using `_controller.close()`, you can use `flag = false`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can show only a part of the bottom sheet by setting the isScrollControlled property to true in the showModalBottomSheet method. This allows the modal bottom sheet to take up only part of the screen and then be dragged up to show the rest of the content.

```
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'This is the partial modal',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16.0),
              Text(
                'Drag up to see more content',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide formatted code?