# Flutter - Expand bottomNavigationBar by swiping or pressing the floatingActionButton

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a main widget called `DashboardWidget`. Inside it, I have a `Scaffold` with `BottomNavigationBar` and a `FloatingActionButton`:

[image]

Now, I want to make a widget that would be dragged from the bottom by:

1. Swiping up with the finger.
2. Pressing on `FloatingActionButton`.

In other words, I want to expand the `BottomNavigationBar`.

[Here's a design concept in case I was unclear.](https://i.gyazo.com/a70f6223966555d60e1dde217b613ad7.mp4)

The problem is, I'm not sure where to start to implement that. I've thought about removing the `BottomNavigationBar` and create a custom widget that can be expanded, but I'm not sure if it's possible either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Output:**

[image]

---

I used a different approach and did it without `AnimationController`, `GlobalKey` etc, the logic code is very short (`_handleClick`).

I only used 4 variables, simple and short!

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  static double _minHeight = 80, _maxHeight = 600;
  Offset _offset = Offset(0, _minHeight);
  bool _isOpen = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF6F6F6),
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF6F6F6), elevation: 0),
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: _handleClick,
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              textColor: Colors.grey,
              child: Text(_isOpen ? "Back" : ""),
            ),
          ),
          Align(child: FlutterLogo(size: 300)),
          GestureDetector(
            onPanUpdate: (details) {
              _offset = Offset(0, _offset.dy - details.delta.dy);
              if (_offset.dy < _HomePageState._minHeight) {
                _offset = Offset(0, _HomePageState._minHeight);
                _isOpen = false;
              } else if (_offset.dy > _HomePageState._maxHeight) {
                _offset = Offset(0, _HomePageState._maxHeight);
                _isOpen = true;
              }
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: AnimatedContainer(
              duration: Duration.zero,
              curve: Curves.easeOut,
              height: _offset.dy,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                  ),
                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5), spreadRadius: 5, blurRadius: 10)]),
              child: Text("This is my Bottom sheet"),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 2 * _HomePageState._minHeight - _offset.dy - 28, // 56 is the height of FAB so we use here half of it.
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(_isOpen ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_down : Icons.add),
              onPressed: _handleClick,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // first it opens the sheet and when called again it closes.
  void _handleClick() {
    _isOpen = !_isOpen;
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 5), (timer) {
      if (_isOpen) {
        double value = _offset.dy + 10; // we increment the height of the Container by 10 every 5ms 
        _offset = Offset(0, value);
        if (_offset.dy > _maxHeight) {
          _offset = Offset(0, _maxHeight); // makes sure it does't go above maxHeight
          timer.cancel();
        }
      } else {
        double value = _offset.dy - 10; // we decrement the height by 10 here
        _offset = Offset(0, value);
        if (_offset.dy < _minHeight) {
          _offset = Offset(0, _minHeight); // makes sure it doesn't go beyond minHeight
          timer.cancel();
        }
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Good job , you will need global key  and such for your code to work on any dimensions not only 600 ,the animated widgets indeed is a good idea

Comment: @SaedNabil Appreciated that, but you don't need `GlobalKey`, just to make things simple I used `600`, else you can use screen size from `MediaQuery` and use how much you want the area to be covered in percent by doing something like `size * 0.9`.

Comment: I understand what you say, I am not try to sell globalkeys ;) , but you will never get it exacly as you want without it . Percentage hight will vary for defferent devices hights , Am I missing somerhing?

Comment: @SaedNabil I am not sure why you really need `GlobalKey`, please ask it as a separate question and I am more than happy to give you a close to perfect answer without using `GlobalKey`. They are just NOT needed here.

Comment: That will be very interesting , Lets learn something new this is the link to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194587/implementing-responsive-ui-without-using-global-keys feel free to give us a good answer :)

Comment: unfortunately , the question put in hold and the fellows in META didn't help in reopening  it I had to delete it to stop the hysteria of down voting , if you still interested you can modify your answer or add a new answer , I upvoted your current answer as it is accepted.

Comment: Thanks for your upvote :) I checked your question and wanted to answer that but it when I saw it was already put on hold, and there is no benefit of adding it as an answer on this post, I will be getting downvotes too. But you can search on internet that you don't really need `GlobalKey` for screen-size stuff.

Comment: Yes, I just regret asking the question It was a How dare you ask a META question party , or How to hate yourself Tutorial :) anyways, You have a chance to support your claim by adding Edit to your answer Don't worry nobody will down voting you unless there is a universal conspiracy trying to prevent the advance of knowledge :)

Comment: @SaedNabil Here is what I was saying, take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3WrA4zAaPw), you don't need `GlobalKey` for working with screen size. I already mentioned in 2nd comment `MediaQuery` is the simplest way to go.

Comment: thanks, for your replay,. I already understand as I mentioned in the comments the only disagreement is the initial assumption that the height is a percentage of the 'MediaQuery' math tells a percentage of a variable is indeed a variable :) i.e 90% of 800pix is different from 90% of 2400pix

Comment: Yes, you are right, percent of a variable is indeed a variable, but if you use `0.8 * screenSize` on different phones with different sizes, you should see all of them are showing you exact width and height of the widget. That's the beauty of `percent * screenSize`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `BottomSheet` class. 
Here is a [Medium-tutorial](https://flutterdoc.com/bottom-sheets-in-flutter-ec05c90453e7) for using that, here is a [youtube-tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_y40_iamKAc) using it and here is the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html) for the class.

The only difference from the tutorials is that you have to add an extra call method for `showBottomSheet` from your `FloatingActionButton` when it is touched.

**Bonus:** here is the [Material Design](https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html#) page on how to use it.

Comment: Hmm ok, but bottomsheet is dragable. What i worried was that he wanted to drag the bottomnavigationbar. There should be a way to that also. Can post a method for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this code, it is a complete example of how to start implementing this kind of UI, take it with a grain of salt.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Orination Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool _isOpen;
  double _dragStart;
  double _hieght;
  double _maxHight;
  double _currentPosition;
  GlobalKey _cardKey;
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _cardAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _isOpen = false;
    _hieght = 50.0;
    _cardKey = GlobalKey();
    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700));
    _cardAnimation = Tween(begin: _hieght, end: _maxHight).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeInOut)
    );

    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _hieght = _cardAnimation.value;
      });
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        titleSpacing: 0.0,
        title: _isOpen
            ? MaterialButton(
          child: Text(
            "Back",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            _isOpen = false;
            _cardAnimation = Tween(begin: _hieght, end: 50.0).animate(
                CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeInOut)
            );
            _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
          },
        )
            : Text(""),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_up),
          onPressed: () {
            final RenderBox renderBoxCard = _cardKey.currentContext
                .findRenderObject();
            _maxHight = renderBoxCard.size.height;
            _cardAnimation = Tween(begin: _hieght, end: _maxHight).animate(
                CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeInOut)
            );
            _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
            _isOpen = true;
          }),
      body: Stack(
        key: _cardKey,
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.black12,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onPanStart: _onPanStart,
            onPanUpdate: _onPanUpdate,
            onPanEnd: _onPanEnd,
            child:Material(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
              ),
              elevation: 60.0,
              color: Colors.white,
             // shadowColor: Colors.,
              child: Container(
                height: _hieght,

                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Hello, You can drag up"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onPanStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    _dragStart = details.globalPosition.dy;

    _currentPosition = _hieght;
  }

  void _onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    final RenderBox renderBoxCard = _cardKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    _maxHight = renderBoxCard.size.height;
    final hieght = _currentPosition - details.globalPosition.dy + _dragStart;
    print(
        "_currentPosition = $_currentPosition _hieght = $_hieght hieght = $hieght");
    if (hieght <= _maxHight && hieght >= 50.0) {
      setState(() {
        _hieght = _currentPosition - details.globalPosition.dy + _dragStart;
      });
    }
  }

  void _onPanEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    _currentPosition = _hieght;
    if (_hieght <= 60.0) {
      setState(() {
        _isOpen = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isOpen = true;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: I modified the code by using Material Widget instead of A container with shadow for better performance,If you have any issue, please let me know .

Comment: Thank you. Although I'de like an explanation of what does what exactly.

Comment: I can help explain , could you please,confirm first that it is working as you expected .